# problem with sessions and redirection php

Tags: php

Im setting a session variable on hypothetical page number 1. The user then clicks a link to go to a site off the server, and then comes back to page number 1. Problem is, the session variables i set on page one, are no longer set when the user comes back.

Is this a known issue with php, is there any work around?

I am starting the session on the page, and i am echoing the session variables after i set them to make sure they set and they are.

Not sure where to go with this.

Comment: Maybe the session timed out or the session ID is not stored in a cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible that the session timeout has expired when the user comes back .. also i think the session has a feature to check for referrers , so u can check that too .. also make sure when the user comes back he lands on the exact same domain

Comment: the last part of your comment, user leaves from http;//website,com but gets sent back to http;//www,website,com (punctuation changed intentionally)

Comment: yeah thats the problem then .. the domain needs to be the exact same .. if this cant be helped .. look into session_set_cookie_params() and make it so that the domain becomes .website.com

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you call `session_start()` in all the scripts that use the session variables?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the session ID in a cookie, and then read that cookie when the user comes back.